# NPoco fetchOneToMany error

Tags: c#, sql, petapoco, npoco

I am trying to use NPoco's fetchOneToMany method to map an object with a list of nested objects, following [this link](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/One-to-Many-Query-Helpers) like so:

```
[TableName("sds_ingredients_ing")]
[PrimaryKey("ing_id")]
public class Ingredient
{
    [Column(Name = "ing_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "ing_cas")]
    public string Cas { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public IList<IngredientLang> Ingredient_Lang;
}

[TableName("sds_ingredients_lang")]
[PrimaryKey("ing_id")]
public class IngredientLang
{
    [Column(Name = "ing_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "lang_id")]
    public int LangId { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the query:

```
List<Ingredient> list = db.FetchOneToMany<Ingredient, IngredientLang>(x => x.Id,
    @"SELECT     ing.*, 
                 lang.*
      FROM       SDS_INGREDIENTS_ING ing 
      LEFT JOIN  SDS_INGREDIENTS_LANG lang 
      ON         ing.ING_ID=lang.ING_ID");
```

Npoco returns the following error: No Property of type ICollection`1 found on object of type: Ingredient, which confuses me because the class Ingredient does have a property of type IList. We've tried List, IList, IEnumerable and pretty much every type of collection we could think of and none of them worked.

Do you have any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: What does the backslash do for ing.\\* and lang.\\*? seems like invalid SQL syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new to stackoverflow and I was using [code] tags, in between witch the '*' character wouldn't show for some reason. I solved it by adding \ before it, c++ style. Then I removed the [code] tags because I realized all you have to do is indent, but I forgot to remove the backslashes. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ingredient_Lang` is not a property. its a field.
If you make it a property it should work.

Comment: Just asking, is the [Ignore] attribute also not a problem? Or do i misinterpreted the annotation?

Comment: You're absolutely right, we fixed it by adding the corresponding get/set methods. My bad for not understanding the difference between fields and properties well, I'm still new to C#.

Thank you! I'd upvote if I had the required amount of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public partial class Graph
 {
    [Reference(ReferenceType.Many, ColumnName = "GraphId", 
     ReferenceMemberName = "GraphId")]
    [Column] public List<Plot> Plots { get; set; }
...
[TableName("Graph")]
[PrimaryKey("GraphId")]
[ExplicitColumns]
public partial class Graph : fooDB.Record<Graph>  
{   
...
```

After stepping through the source for NPoco 3.2.0, I learned that I needed to put [Column] on the List member to elicit the intended child-parent in my classes after invoking FetchOneToMany:

```
results = tdb.FetchOneToMany<Graph>(g => g.Plots, _plotsByReview, reviewId);
```

Also, keep your select columns contiguous with the child columns after the parent:

```
private static string _plotsByReview = @"
        select 
        g.GraphId,
        g.GraphName,
        g.UserId,
        g.Shared,
        g.ReviewId,
        p.PlotId as Plots__PlotId,
        p.GraphId as Plots__GraphId,
        p.TagId as Plots__TagId,
        p.YAxis as Plots__YAxis,
        p.Relabel as Plots__Relabel,
        p.Scale as Plots__Scale,
        p.MinY as Plots__MinY,
        p.MaxY as Plots__MaxY
        from [Graph] g
        inner join [Plot] p on p.GraphId = g.GraphId
        where g.ReviewId = @0
    ";
```

NPoco rules!!!